# How to make React native app responsive screen according to phone's screen size for both tablets or average android phone

Tags: android, react-native, user-interface, screen

I have a pin code screen in react native app and I want make it responsive/enlarge according to the phone or tablets size like I have a logo in screen or any other components are visible small in tablets but in normal simulators it is average I want to make it large according to tablet's size

Here are some screenshots

[image: Phone's screen]

[image: Teblet's screen]

I want to enlarge tablet's screen item as visible in an average phone

Comment: Please provide your code for this screen so we can assist you better.

Answer (score 1):

> Dimensions use for image and buttons
> [click this link and read Documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions)

Example

```
    Height: Dimensions.get('window').height / 2.5,
    Width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 2.5,
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but its not what exactly I want... at this time I want to enlarge my components when app is installed on tablet and make small components when I install the apk. Also I want to wrap the whole component not every single component

Comment: Its fine I have made it via react-native-responsive-screen package

Answer (score 0):

You can use the screen's aspect ratio (height/width) to ensure the size of your buttons/icons/margins remain proportional on all screen sizes & device types (including tablets)

Use the following function and pass it a number to get a new number that considers the screen's aspect ratio:

```
export const responsiveSize = (number: number): number => {
  const currentScreen = Dimensions.get('window')
  return (currentScreen.height / currentScreen.width) * number
}
```